# Run SQL update statement after dataprep job started from trigger - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

A Dataprep job is run from a trigger which is fired when a file has been written to a bucket.
I need to run a SQL update statement on BigQuery immediately after the Dataprep job has finished.
Not sure how I can get the SQL to run immediately after the Dataprep job has finished?

Answer (score 0):

SQL scripts could be part of output run. Those script run before or after the publication

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run SQL update statements on BigQuery after the Dataprep job, in the Run job tab we can see the Add script option in the bottom there update script can be added.

[image]

The Add SQL Script tab looks as below.

[image]

Comment: Is this new functionality in DataPrep?

Comment: @JonathanRoberts On July 20, 2021 after the release of version 8.5 of Trifacta, a feature of creating  [SQL script](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Release+Notes+for+Cloud+Dataprep#ReleaseNotesforCloudDataprep-July20,2021) was added.